# How can I get the device token in this statement?

Tags: php, mysql

My database schema has a `device_token` field in the login table. I want to select it when this statement is called.

```
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);
    //Use the result of one php function in another php file
```

The thing is the statement above uses a join and I'll need help selecting the `device_token` from the login table given the current syntax. My ultimate goal is to echo the `device_token` so I want to:

- Select it in the statement above
- Store it in a variable
- Echo it out

How can one do this?

**Updated code**

```
SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.title, l.IdUser, p.username, l.device_token FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto
```

**Edit 2**

Here is the whole statement

```
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    // load the last 50 photos from the "photos" table, also join the "login" so that you can fetch the 
    // usernames of the photos' authors
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50");

} else {
    //do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);
    //Use the result of one php function in another php file
    //Either result or idphoto since idphoto can successfully get the photo we want etc
    //if i store id photo can i query idphoto based on idphoto like above?
    //get device token here?

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.title, l.IdUser, p.username, l.device_token FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto=%d LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);

while ($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $row['device_token'];
}
}
```

Comment: You should learn about prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Remove the singlequotes around `%d`, because this will not needed for numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting `l.device_token` in your query that's why you are not able to get the value of `device_token`.

```
SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.title, l.IdUser, p.username, l.device_token FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto=%d LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto
```

For fetching the data

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.title, l.IdUser, p.username, l.device_token FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto=%d LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);

while ($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo $row['device_token'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. That will help me a lot.

Comment: @Program1 : you can correct my answer so it can help others in future.

Comment: The thing is, the first php statement I posted in my question is already being sed in my app successfully.

Comment: I want to use the select statement you provided. Is there a way i can print the `device_token`using the first select statement you posted?

Comment: I posted the whole `stream` function I am using in my app. I edited it with the select statement you provided that gets the `device_token` and the while statement that prints the row too too. Can you help me verify that the syntax is correct? Is the while statement in the right place? I will run the app and see if i can get it to print. update in progress, thank you

Comment: @Jens said true. You should not use `mysql` it is deprecated.

Comment: thats okay for now. believe it or not, the data isn't that sensitive

Comment: I posted the whole `stream` function I am using in my app. I edited it with all the code you provided. ill run the app and see what happens. thank you. i may have to ask a new question to verify the print functionality

Comment: I accepted your answer because from reading your code, that looks to be the correct way to get the associated `device_token` thanks!

Comment: how should i go about trying to print post data? should i just ask a new question?

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST)`. use this if you are talking about the getting data by `POST` method

Comment: since the page isn't `AJAX` I have to keep refreshing it while calling the stream command from my app. Is there an easier way to verify the token value? On second thought I don't think a print is the best way.

Comment: You can ask a different question regarding the issues you are facing with a proper description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105221/discussion-between-program1-and-urfusion).